# extract numerical suffixes from strings in R

Tags: r, string, character

I have this character vector:

```
variables <- c("ret.SMB.l1", "ret.mkt.l1", "ret.mkt.l4", "vix.l4", "ret.mkt.l5" "vix.l6", "slope.l11",  "slope.l12", "us2yy.l2")
```

Desired output:

```
> suffixes(variables)
[1] 1 1 4 4 5 6 11 12 2
```

In other words, I need a function that will return a numeric vector showing the suffixes (each of which be 1 or 2 digits long). Note, I need something that can work with a much larger number of strings which may or may not have numbers somewhere the middle. The numerical suffixes range from 1 to 99.

Many thanks

Comment: These answers both use regex ("regular expressions", the part with the `.*`, etc.), which you may want to read up on if you encounter problems like this frequently. Typing `?regex` in R is a good place to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `gsub`:

```
> gsub(".*?([0-9]+)$", "\\1", variables)
[1] "1"  "1"  "4"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "11" "12" "2"
```

Wrap it in `as.numeric` if you want the result as a number.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sub` function.

```
> variables <- c("ret.SMB.l1", "ret.mkt.l1", "ret.mkt.l4", "vix.l4", "ret.mkt.l5" ,"vix.l6", "slope.l11",  "slope.l12", "us2yy.l2")
> sub(".*\\D", "", variables)
[1] "1"  "1"  "4"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "11" "12" "2"
```

`.*\\D` matches all the characters from the start upto the last non-digit character. Replacing those matched characters with an empty string will give you the desired output.